# Passing a variable to another form, from another when invoked by an action

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I might be making this more complicated than I have to.

I have a form in Visual Basic that is adding a row of data to an Access Database.

What will happen (or rather what I would like to happen) is that when the form is created, a row will be added to said database. Once that row is added, I want to have another form open (called NewWindowA) which will pull information on that database that is related to the ID of the row that was created from the first form.

I know that in NewWindowA I need to have the form load the values on Load. But my question is: How do you pass a value to a new window that's invoked by some action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a constructor of newwindowa that takes the id Like :

```
Public Sub New(ByVal ID as Integer) 
   'Do stuff
End Sub
```

Another Choice you have that you make a global property in newwindowa

```
Private _ID As Integer
Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get 
        Return _ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _ID = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When you want to call neweindowa:

```
Dim n as New NewWindowA
n.ID = 12312
n.Show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method to pass a variable to a custom task pane? I don't seem to be able to add a property to a custom task pane.

Answer (score 4):

just create a **public** sub in the new form possibly called (prepareUI)
that new sub has the parameter you want to pass as its parameters
access the controls and fill them .

in the original form 
instantiate the new form and call the show method
and then call the sub prepareUI sending the paremateres you need